# Is any of this the proper way to design with different devices in mind using xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, xcode6

I have three different alternatives to design a view, at least three that I could think of / understand from different blog posts and SO questions. The layout is pretty simple, some labels and textfields to provide a login. The thing is that it should adapt to any device screen (iPhones portrait for now to limit scope).

Each one of the three alternatives seem to have pros and cons, but I want to **understand** which one (if any) is the ***proper way in which we are supposed to design*** with adaptative layout, size classes and universal storyboards in mind.

Please, don't hesitate to point me wrong!

1.- Design on `Any W | Any H` size class, and once I'm happy with the default design move on to specific situations:
[image]

The issue here is that there isn't a size class that allows me to specify a constraint only for 3.5inch devices (all cases I tried affect none or several). Therefore, I don't know how to properly define a specific constraint that overrides the default one in this unique case.

2.- Same as before, design on `Any W | Any H` but using smaller gaps between elements.
[image]

It looks as good as it gets in smaller devices, but a whole lot of space is lost in bigger ones as the constraints don't adapt. Maybe constraints should be overridden in this case, which would be the inverse case as the previous point.

3.- Use a subview hierarchy to distribute the elements.
[image]

Embedding elements in subviews inside other subviews I managed to have a dynamic layout that adapts to the height of the screen, but it doesn't look right at all in bigger screens. The subviews are expected to take up the same height, but I'm not sure this is quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

i think it really depends what you want, its hard for us to tell you what your app should be like, although i would think the last case is what you would most likely want (in general, for a login page like this i would choose number 2), i think it can be achieved without using subviews though, try setting each textfield to having a vertical center, and set the multiplier to a value that puts it in the right place, then it should stick proportionally where its supposed to be

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I really want, so I asked mostly to know what's the proper/expected/best way to work with this. And also how should I start laying out my views to take advantage of Size Classes and Adaptability with the minimum effort. Thanks for the advice on setting multiplier values for centering; gonna try it.